# c++ container inside another container

Tags: c++, c++20

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

template <typename T>
struct Row {
    Row() { puts("Row default"); }
    Row(const Row& other) { puts("Row copy"); }
    Row(Row&& other) { puts("Row move"); }
    Row(T x) { puts("Row int"); }
};

int main() {
  Row<Row<int>> x (10); // this works
  Row<Row<int>> x2 = 10; // error
}
```

Why the code doesn't work? I know that first one performs direct initialization and the second one is copy initialization but still when it comes to container inside a container I doesn't get easy for me.

compiler: clang c++20

Error message:

> no viable conversion from 'int' to 'Row<Row >'
>
> Row<Row> x2 = 10

Comment: Please make a [mcve] - something anyone with a standard compliant compiler can compile. Hint: `#include <bits/stdc++.h>` doesn't include a standard header.

Comment: You need to implement `operator =(...)`.

Answer (score 10):

Problem is that [copy initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_initialization) is less permissive than direct initialization:

```
> In addition, the implicit conversion in copy-initialization must produce T
  directly from the initializer, while, e.g. direct-initialization expects
  an implicit conversion from the initializer to an argument of T's constructor.
```

as initialization from `int` requires 2 conversions (from `int` to `Row<int>` and from `Row<int>` to `Row<Row<int>>`), direct initialization allows it but copy initialization does not. You can see it in documentation example as well:

```
struct S { S(std::string) {} }; // implicitly convertible from std::string
S s("abc"); // OK: conversion from const char[4] to std::string
S s = "abc"; // Error: no conversion from const char[4] to S
S s = "abc"s; // OK: conversion from std::string to S
```

Answer (score 1):

In

```
Row<Row<int>> x2 = 10;
```

rather than assignment operator being invoked, the copy-initialisation happens which you mentioned as well. Copy-initialisation calls the copy (or move) constructor of the object, which requires you to pass the object by reference as an argument, which is clearly not possible with the `int` 10 that you are passing. To make it work, you would have to provide a valid type to copy from:

```
Row<Row<int>> x2 = Row<int>(10);
```

From the [copy-constructor reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_constructor):

> A copy constructor of class T is a non-template constructor whose first parameter is T&‍, const T&‍, volatile T&‍, or const vola

Comment: Copy-initialization doesn’t necessarily invoke a copy/move constructor since C++17; there’s simply a special rule to prevent a second conversion here ([over.best.ics]/4).

Answer (score 1):

This is what compiler will probably generate(reference [cppinsights](https://cppinsights.io/)) for the first call

```cpp
/* First instantiated from: insights.cpp:12 */
#ifdef INSIGHTS_USE_TEMPLATE
template<>
struct Row<int>
{
  inline Row();
  
  inline Row(const Row<int> & other);
  
  inline Row(Row<int> && other);
  
  inline Row(int x)
  {
    puts("Row int");
  }
  
};

#endif


/* First instantiated from: insights.cpp:12 */
#ifdef INSIGHTS_USE_TEMPLATE
template<>
struct Row<Row<int> >
{
  inline Row();
  
  inline Row(const Row<Row<int> > & other);
  
  inline Row(Row<Row<int> > && other);
  
  inline Row(Row<int> x)
  {
    puts("Row int");
  }
  
};

#endif


int main()
{
  Row<Row<int> > x = Row<Row<int> >(Row<int>(10));
}
```

and your output will be
`Row int Row int`

on `Row int` from the first template instantiation and one from the second

When you are trying

```cpp
Row<Row<int>> x2 = 10;
```

compiler converts `10` to `int` but it is enable to find such instantiation which can convert directly `int` to `Row<Row<int>>`. This will require 2 conversions.

So either you provide one conversion by yourself or use direct initialization.